# Getting error "Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance." while trying to execute expression tree in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

In C#, I have a class `MyNamespace.MyClass`, and in that class there is defined a method `MyMethod`. I am trying to call this method upon `MyObject`, an instance of the `MyClass` class, but I am getting the error in the title. Here is my code:

```
Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"), Expression.Constant("MyParam"))).Compile().Method.Invoke(MyObject, null);
```

`MyMethod` is not a static method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code or we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of `Expression.Call` that takes the MethodInfo first is for static methods.  You need this one: [Expression.Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_), eg to compile a delegate that calls `myObject.MyMethod("MyParam")` would be:

```
    var f = (Action)Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(myObject), typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"),  Expression.Constant("MyParam"))).Compile();

    f();
```